# Рейтинг в онлайн игре фортнайт

Tags: разработка-игр

Каким образом получить рейтинг игры (список типа (ник;место)) после игры на сервере в онлайн игре Fortnite. пока сам не догадался, может написать приложение которое будет засекать время "жизни" Каждого игрока. После чего будет определятся кто дольше прожил и т.д. .
После игры в самом fortnite рейтинг не отображается. Можно ли реализовать данную задачу каким-то образом проще?

Comment: ты разраб фортнайта ?

Comment: Нет, я разраб другого проекта где нужна эта инфа